# SFDX CI: Invalid record ID. Specify valid record ID value

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, continuous-integration, jsforce, ci

I'm trying to follow [Continuous Integration Using Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_travis_ci) trailhead module, however, I'm using my own repo (I didn't clone the sample repo that is provided).

I've used their [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/smukov/sfdx-ci-practice/blob/216b1da2980b742161bcb392c77d3ea3933ff6f6/.travis.yml) file and I followed all the steps, so a Travis build is properly started whenever I push to my repo. I can see that the JWT-based authentication passes correctly, as well. However, the script always fails at the below line 498:

[image]

I tried running the above line directly from my local machine in the same project, connected to the same DevHub and it works, it creates a scratch org without a problem. I'm not sure what could be the issue?

---

**UPDATE**

Something weird is going on here. Build fails 9/10 times, even if I'm not changing `.travis.yml` or any relevant files (e.g. - just by updating `README.md` file, or re-running the build, it sometimes passes, but most of the time it still fails).

---

Below is the full stack trace that gets returned when I include the `--json` flag:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid record ID. Specify valid record ID value",
  "status": 1,
  "stack": "Error: Invalid record ID. Specify valid record ID value
    at /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/jsforce/lib/connection.js:572:40
    at /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/lodash/core.js:785:25
    at /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/lodash/core.js:1049:13
    at baseMap (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/lodash/core.js:784:5)
    at Function.map (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/lodash/core.js:2033:12)
    at module.exports.Connection.retrieve (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/jsforce/lib/connection.js:571:7)
    at module.exports.SObject.retrieve (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/jsforce/lib/sobject.js:78:21)
    at _getConnection.then (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/force.js:387:106)
    at tryCatcher (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/sfdx-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)",
  "name": "Error",
  "warnings": [
    "All --json output, including on error, is moving to stdout. Use the SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT environment variable to move over to the new functionality. This will become the default in version 45."
  ]
}
```

---

**Final update**

I switched to GitLab Runners and the same script worked fine. I can only conclude that there is some underlying issue with Travis builds, but I don't how to solve it.

Comment: Maybe add the `--json` and `--logLevel error` flags to see if it shows anything else up, such as a clue about what the ID might be.

Comment: Are there any IDs in the definition file? I doubt it, but if there are it seems a viable candidate. If there aren't, I'd say this is a platform bug.

Comment: @MattLacey No ID in the definition file. It's very basic, you can see it [here](https://github.com/smukov/sfdx-ci-practice/blob/31879849f29145ef9947774b63fda4b3c6982e39/config/project-scratch-def.json).

Comment: @DanielBallinger the `--json` flag just gave me a stack trace back, the error is exactly the same. The stack trace says that the problem is happening in `jsforce` libray: `sfdx-cli/node_modules/jsforce/lib/connection.js:572:40`

Comment: @smukov Can you include the full stack trace in the question? It's likely the problem originated in whatever is calling the jsforce library.

Comment: @DanielBallinger updated the question with the full stack trace.

Comment: Whatever happened at line 378 in `salesforce-alm/dist/lib/force.js` called `sobject.retrieve` for a single undefined id. Beyond that reads as bluebird/lodash noise to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actual solution:

So I spoke to Tavis CI and they suggested testing the job again with the following extra configuration:

before_install:
- unset CI
- unset TRAVIS
- unset CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION

So far has worked every time for me with this added

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the " -v HubOrg " option is causing the issue.

> -v | --targetdevhubusername TARGETDEVHUBUSERNAME
>   Optional
>   A username or alias for the target Dev Hub org. Overrides the default Dev Hub org.

I tried it using the alias of the Dev Hub Org  and it seems to work fine. It went past the step:

> sfdx force:apex:test:run -u testorg1 --wait 10

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? the question shows that smukov is already using the -v option

Comment: meant that the value provided in the example script  "-v HubOrg", "HubOrg" should be a valid alias for the Org where you have the Env. Hub setup and to which you have authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

So, pretty sure that this is a Travis CI thing... I've been fighting this for a bit last week myself and have managed to get a build reliably completing using Circle CI instead of Travis. Instructions and example repo here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-circleci